# Emacsで、ScalaのWorksheetを行なう方法はありますか

Tags: scala, emacs

Eclipseや、IntelliJ IDEAのWorksheet機能をEmacsでも行いたいです。

https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started